# Replace string content between quotes in file

Tags: powershell

I have made this loop to iterate some files that I want to replace content in.

The content that I want to replace is a string which can look something like this: `foo="1"`.

What I need your help with is how to find the string (regexp I guess) and update the file with a new value, like `2` for example.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.config"

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Get-Content $file.FullName
}

Read-Host
```

Comment: You can use escape characters to identify double quotes literally for e.g.  "`"" will give you a literal Double Quote symbol

Comment: Are you working with xml or text files? Do you the exact string you want to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sample code in the question, I assume you're attempting to update a .NET configuration file (ie. a `web.config` or `app.config` file).

Given that these files are really XML files, you may want to treat them as such:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.config"

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    # Create an XmlDocument object from the file
    $configXml = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName)

    # Find all the nodes in the document
    $xmlNodes  = $configXml.SelectNodes('//*')

    # Keep track of whether we make changes or not
    $changeCount = 0

    foreach($node in $xmlNodes)
    {
        # Check if node has a "foo" attribute
        if($node.HasAttribute('foo'))
        {
            # Set 2 as the value
            $node.SetAttribute('foo',2)
            $changeCount++
        }
    }

    if($changeCount)
    {
        # At least one node was updated, save to file
        $configXml.Save($file.FullName)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about the config files. Thanks for a nice example

Comment: It seems like `$configXml` is null, even though the file is found? Perhaps it can't cast it to an xml? `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` on `$configXml.SelectNodes('//*')`

Comment: If `$configXml = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw)` doesn't work, try with `$configXml = New-Object xml; $configXml.Load($file.FullName)` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can try regex. Ex.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.config"

$find = 'foo=".*?"'
$replace = 'foo="4"'

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Get-Content $file.FullName |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $find, $replace } |
        Set-Content $file.Fullname
    }
}

Read-Host
```

Or to only modify files that match:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.config"

$find = 'foo=".*?"'
$replace = 'foo="4"'

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName
    if(Select-String -InputObject $content -Pattern $find -Quiet) {
        $content |
        Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $find, $replace } |
        Set-Content $file.Fullname
    }
}

Read-Host
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was unclear on one part though: I don't know the content of the initial tag. So I think regexp is needed to match `foo="something unknown"`, right? That's where I'm stuck

Comment: And why would someone downvote this? :S The previous answer was exactly what the question asked for. The question suggested using regex, but it didn't say that the "find"-string was unknown/pattern. People use regex for static text-replacement too.

Comment: Do you know what you need to replace?  For instance, are you always replacing anything between the quotes with a 5, or does the source determine what you place inside?  This could be kind of complex...

Comment: I didn't think so. It was for the guy doing the drive-by. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should answer your question

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.config"

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $fileContent = Get-Content $file.FullName
    $newContent = $fileContent -replace 'foo="1"', 'foo="2"'
    Set-Content $file.FullName $newContent
}
```

Further reading here: [Use PowerShell to Replace Text in Strings](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings.aspx)